# Google Forms Calendar Widget with Date Elimination

Tags: google-forms

Long story short - I have a Google Form that has a calendar on it for project due dates. I have the form linked up as an integration to Monday.com that adds lead time when it populates in a queue.

What I want, is to have Google Forms automatically "gray" days starting from "today" up to four business days (Monday to Friday).

Is this a feature that is being overlooked? Or is it something that needs to be coded in?

Just curious how I can implement this process into my form for a more consistent workflow.

[image]

Comment: Is the form that you have linked up to monday.com an html form of your own design or are you implying that it's a google form and if it's a google form how does Monday.com submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to customize the "calendar widget" in Google Forms.

NOTE: Google usually don't mention on the documentation the features that aren't included; the Google Forms editor doesn't include any way to do that and Google Apps Script Forms service either.

Reference

- https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9991170?hl=en
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms